# Yandex Maps Zoom Control

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Встраиваю карты в мобильное приложение. Мне понадобилось сделать управление масштабом карты в виде двух круглых кнопок (+) и (-). Взял пример от Яндекс, слегка изменил и сделал свой zoomControl (код см. ниже). Но вот незадача - при двойном щелчке  кнопки увеличиваются вместе с картой. Пробовал навешивать обработчик на dblclick на ZoomControl и на всю карту, пробовал фильтровать события сlick, но все это не помогло.

```
// Creating a custom layout for the zoom slider.

ZoomLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass("<div>" +

"<div id='zoom-in' class='button'><img src='mb2capp://plus.png' width='100px' height='100px'></div><br>" +

"<div id='zoom-out' class='button'><img src='mb2capp://minus.png' width='100px' height='100px'></div>" +

"</div>", {

/**

* Redefining methods of the layout, in order to perform

* additional steps when building and clearing the layout.

*/

build: function () {

// Calling the "build" parent method.

ZoomLayout.superclass.build.call(this);

/**

* Binding handler functions to the context and storing references

* to them in order to unsubscribe from the event later.

*/

this.zoomInCallback = ymaps.util.bind(this.zoomIn, this);

this.zoomOutCallback = ymaps.util.bind(this.zoomOut, this);

// Beginning to listen for clicks on the layout buttons.

$('#zoom-in').bind('click', this.zoomInCallback);

$('#zoom-out').bind('click', this.zoomOutCallback);

},

clear: function () {

// Removing click handlers.

$('#zoom-in').unbind('click', this.zoomInCallback);

$('#zoom-out').unbind('click', this.zoomOutCallback);

// Calling the "clear" parent method.

ZoomLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);

},

zoomIn: function () {

var map = this.getData().control.getMap();

map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1, {checkZoomRange: true});

},

zoomOut: function () {

var map = this.getData().control.getMap();

map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1, {checkZoomRange: true});

}

}),

zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({options: {layout: ZoomLayout}});

myMap.controls.add(zoomControl, { float: 'none', position: {right: '50px', top: '250px'} });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте на страницу meta например такую `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`
Подробней можно почитать тут: https://www.w3schools.com/cSS/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то часть кода искорежилась при отправке. Вначале стоит следующий код:

// Creating a custom layout for the zoom slider.
ZoomLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass("" +
"
" +
"" +
"", {

/**
* Redefining methods of the layout, in order to perform
* additional steps when building and clearing the layout.
*/
build: function () { ...